# Duplicated background on Watermark / Placeholder Combobox WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, combobox

I am having some problems trying to set a PlaceHolder Text in a combobox in WPF.

This is my XAML code.

```
<ComboBox DockPanel.Dock="Right" x:Name="cbExtractBy" Width="150" SelectedIndex="-1" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <VisualBrush x:Key="ExtractByPlaceHolder" AlignmentX="Left" AlignmentY="Center" Stretch="None">
            <VisualBrush.Visual>
                <Label Content="Extract By" Foreground="Gray" />
            </VisualBrush.Visual>
        </VisualBrush>
    </ComboBox.Resources>

    <ComboBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="ComboBox">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <Trigger Property="SelectedIndex" Value="-1">
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="{StaticResource ExtractByPlaceHolder}" />
                </Trigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.Style>
</ComboBox>
```

This is the result I am getting.

[image: Image Result]

I also tried to replace this line

```
<Label Content="Extract By" Foreground="Gray" />
```

with this

```
<TextBlock Text="Extract By" Foreground="Gray" />
```

but I still have the same result.

I am using Visual Studio 2013 and .Net Framework 4.5.
Is there anyone that have had this problem?

Comment: I cannot reproduce this, try another machine (other graphics card, up to date drivers)

Comment: If I put a solid background color it looks like it has been painted twice but it is readable.  The problem happens when I don't put any background or I put a transparent background.

Comment: I copy-pasted the code in the question into a new WPF solution. Please update the code in the question so it fully reproduces the problem.

Comment: The code above is all the code I have.  When I mentioned the background it is just add **<Label Content="Extract By" Foreground="Gray" Background="White"/>** instead of **<Label Content="Extract By" Foreground="Gray" />**